# Access denied on mysql database using openshift

Tags: mysql, node.js, openshift

I am trying to get to deploy my nodejs app to openshift but I'm having a particularly annoying problem with communication with mysql.

I can access the mysql db through port forwarding (127.0.0.1:3307 local -> 127.11.255.130:3306) using my local client and I have populated the database no probs.
I then try to access the db using my node.js script (running on the same domain in openshift):

```
  var connection  = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '127.11.255.130',
    user     : 'usernameissued',
    password : 'passwordissued',
    database : 'cpapi'
  });

  connection.connect(); // blows up here
  connection.query("SELECT id, firstname, lastname from users", function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;

  });
  connection.end();
```

The exception thrown is :

ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'usernameissued'@'127.11.255.130' (using password: YES)

I have even altered all of the permissions for that user granting full access and it still doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had/have the same problem (for the last hour) and found a semi-solution - create users with empty passwords. I can speculate the issue is in how the "mysql" module hashes passwords. I have no idea if the issue came with the last version of "mysql" module - always use empty passwords on my local machine :)

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this, really appreciate the advice.  Thanks to everyone else for their help too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not entered any data into mysql yet, I would remove the mysql cartridge and re-install it.  If you have entered data, do a mysqldump first, and then remove/reinstall the mysql cartridge.  What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately I've already tried that with no joy. I'm using version 5.1.

Comment: Is this on a scaled application?  When you say you can access it over a port forward, did you use the same code, and just change the port it is trying to access? (3306 -> 3307)